# Add a time offset to triggers in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming query that I set up roughly in the following way:

```py
(
    df
    .writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .options("...")  # Some Kafka options
    .trigger(processingTime='1 minute')
    .start()
)
```

Because of the way Spark schedules jobs, microbatches are executed every full minute (14:10:00, 14:11:00, 14:12:00, etc.).

However, I need them to be executed 20 seconds after the full minute: 14:10:20, 14:11:20, 14:12:20, etc. Is that possible?

I'm not necessary looking for an API-based solution (I don't see `Trigger` class supporting this). A workaround will work too.